# Get latest artifact from maven nexus for a certain minor version

Tags: maven, nexus

in my nexus 2 repository i have following structure:

```
snaphosts/ 
  com/example/group/ 
    artifact/
      1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
      1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
      1.0.2-SNAPSHOT
      1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
      1.1.1-SNAPSHOT
```

When i query:
http://ip/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/content?g=com.example.group&a=artifact&v=LATEST&r=snapshots

Then i get 1.1.1-SNAPSHOT.

My question is how can i get the latest 1.0 version? Is there a query that downloads 1.0.2-SNAPSHOT?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update a POM with latest versions in the 1.0.x range, I would use the versions maven plugin. It is unlikely that Nexus 2 has such a feature.